# margin-left is getting duplicated/multiplied

Tags: html, css, margin

I really can't get why, somehow `margin-left` is just affecting other elements, which is very annoying.

```css
.setting-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
.setting-topnav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #081723;
}

.setting-topnav a {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: NanumGothic;
  color: #fafafa;

  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 43px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.setting-title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0px;
}

.setting-title a {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: NanumGothic;
  color: #fafafa;

  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 43px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar_template"></div> 
<div class="setting-container">
    <div class="setting-topnav">
        <a>Setting　/　Basic Configuration<a>
    </div>

    <div class="setting-title">
        <a>Basic Configuration<a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could it be that you aren't properly closing your `<a>` tags leaving the browser to interpret intent?

Comment: wow I feel so dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your a tags:

```
<div id="navbar_template"></div> 
<div class="setting-container">
    <div class="setting-topnav">
        <a>Setting　/　Basic Configuration</a>
    </div>

    <div class="setting-title">
        <a>Basic Configuration</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, It helped to fix my stupiditiy